# How can I stop active record callbacks from throwing an error when they fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, redis, sidekiq

I have a Rails app that includes some `after_save` active record callbacks, which are responsible for updating a second cache database.

Recently I was having some load issues and the second database was slow to respond or refusing connections, and my users started getting 500 errors when they tried to save objects.

I think this was down to me misunderstanding how callbacks work - I assumed that by making these `after_save` rather than `before_save`, the user was "safe" and if the callback failed, that would be graceful and silent.

**How might I refactor my code to stop this behaviour and avoid exposing my users to error messages when these callbacks fail?**

I've looked at refactoring the callbacks to simply trigger an active job, like this:

```
# models/mymodel.rb

after_save :update_index

def update_index
    UpdateIndexJob.perform_later(self)
end
```

The active job includes the logic for actually updating the second cache database.

I'm not sure whether I would also need to implement sidekiq and redis for this to work.

I've also read about [rails observers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531514/observers-vs-callbacks), which apparently work similar to callbacks but don't break the request-response cycle when they fail.

Comment: Can you include some logs?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop active record callbacks from throwing an error when they fail?

That's a very open question, and I think you've already answered it yourself.

You can either:

1. Rewrite it in such a way that it **won't** fail (e.g. only invoke a background task).
2. Rescue the exception. (But then, is aborting that path of the code actually a sensible decision?! Probably not.)

> I've looked at refactoring the callbacks to simply trigger an active job [...] I'm not sure whether I would also need to implement sidekiq and redis for this to work.

That seems like a safe implementation. And **yes**, you will need to configure a backend in order to actually execute the jobs. See [the documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#job-execution). Sidekiq, Resque, Sneakers, Sucker Punch, Queue Classic, Delayed Job and Que are just some of the available choices.

> I've also read about rails observers ...

That would also prevent user errors, but **what happens if it fails** due to an intermittent timeout?? One of the core features of background jobs is that they **retry** on failure.

Therefore I would advise using a background job instead of an observer for this.

---

Now with all of that said, we've barely spoken about *what problem you're trying to solve*:

> updating a second cache database

You've said very little able what the "second cache database" actually is, but I *suspect* this could actually be configured as a [leader/follower database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases), and live completely outside of your application.